# can we adjust express middlewere for special requests

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

#### app.use()

```js
app.use(express.json()) // this is assigned to ALL requests
```

what can be equivalent to

```js
app.use(/*Only POST AND PUT*/,express.json()) // this is assigned to ALL requests
```

Answer (score 1):

[express-conditional-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-conditional-middleware) allows:

```
const conditional = require('express-conditional-middleware');

app.use(conditional(req => ['POST', 'PUT'].includes(req.method), express.json()));
```